# Issue regarding saving the outputs of a loop to .csv file

Tags: c++, csv

I am new here to programming. I have an issue regarding saving the outputs of a loop to .csv file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <ios>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>


#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/videoio/videoio.hpp"

#include "opencv2/core/cvdef.h"
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>

#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include "opencv2/core/ptr.inl.hpp"

#include "dirent.h"
#include "windows.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d.hpp"

#include "opencv2/flann/miniflann.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"

#include <opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp>

#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"



using namespace cv;
using namespace std;





#define SHOW_RESULTS 
typedef long SLONG;
typedef LARGE_INTEGER TIMER;
static SLONG
flag_timer_setup = 0;
static LARGE_INTEGER
lpTimerFrequency;

//-------------------------------------------------------
void SYS_reset_timer ( TIMER *tick )
//-------------------------------------------------------
{
if( flag_timer_setup == 0)
{
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&lpTimerFrequency);
flag_timer_setup = 1;
}

QueryPerformanceCounter( tick );

}

//-------------------------------------------------------
SLONG SYS_get_timer_us           ( TIMER *tick)
//-------------------------------------------------------
{
TIMER
lpPerformanceCountEnd;
QueryPerformanceCounter( &lpPerformanceCountEnd );

return ((SLONG)(0xFFFFFFFF & ((lpPerformanceCountEnd.QuadPart - tick->QuadPart) * 1000000L / lpTimerFrequency.QuadPart)) );
}

int testBlur(Mat sourceImage, Mat & destinationImage, float & time)
{

TIMER tic;

/// test parameters
int filterSize = 11;
int N = 1000;
int time1;
if( sourceImage.empty()) // Check for invalid input
{
cout <<  "Invelid input image" << std::endl ;
return -1;
}


for (filterSize =1; filterSize <11; filterSize+=1)
{
    SYS_reset_timer(&tic);  

for(int i =0; i<N; i++)
{
    // filter the image
    blur(sourceImage, destinationImage, cvSize(filterSize, filterSize));

}

SLONG elapsed_time = SYS_get_timer_us(&tic);
float elapsed_time_seconds = elapsed_time/1000.0f;
float el = (elapsed_time_seconds)/N;

cout<< "blur"<< el<<endl;
time = el;
}


return 0;

}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])

{
Mat sourceImage, destImage, temp, desttImage, detect;
Mat grad,src,distanceTransform;
int scale = 1;
int delta = 0;
float time;
int ddepth = -1;    


////////
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("Elapsed Time For Image Filtering.csv");

//load image
sourceImage = imread("../images/man.tiff",IMREAD_GRAYSCALE); // load and convert to grayscale
if( sourceImage.empty() )                      // Check for invalid input                                           
{
cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
return -1;
}








// call test function for blur
testBlur(sourceImage, destImage,time);
myfile << "Blur;"<<time<<time<<endl;
imwrite("blur.bmp", destImage);

//show results
#ifdef  SHOW_RESULTS
namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE ); // Create a window for display.
imshow( "Display window", destImage );                // Show our image inside it.
//waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
#endif
```

I converted the images and used some filter function and added timer to test the tick and toc and I added the for loop by  hanging the value of the filtersize and I'm unable to save the ten outputs of the testblur to .csv file. Please let me know how should print the output of the for loop of test blur to the .csv file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do not include unnecessary stuff for the title. Eg:- Hi everyone.... Pls edit this question in properly.

Comment: @ChandanaKumara:how to edit and I didn't get what you said,I have an issue to save the ten outputs of the test blur function which I can get in the display but unable to store in .csv file ,it would be great if you help me in this issue

Comment: I changed your question. Pls check.